# How to get focusable elements of div with nested divs of the same class?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to get focusable elements of div with class accordion but skip elements of nested divs with the same class. I tried to recreate problem in the simplified code created in codepen https://codepen.io/michal-zygiel/pen/KKeGbyO but it still get all of the buttons and anchors (only these elements for now to simplify selector in codepen). There can be more wrappers with other classes inside but the point is to get only "parent accordion's" links and buttons.

HTML

```
<div class="accordion">
    <div class="accordion-content">
        <a href="#">link</a>
        <button>button</button>
        <div class="accordion">
            <div class="accordion-content">
                <button>button inside nested accordion</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
const accordionElement = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion")[0];
const accordionContent = accordionElement.getElementsByClassName("accordion-content")[0];
const accordionFocusableElements = accordionContent.querySelectorAll("div:not(.accordion) a, div:not(.accordion) button");
```

Expected output would be [a, button] but for now it's [a, button, button]

Comment: Use [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) ..?

Comment: @Teemu I don't think it will work when there is added wrapper around let's say link inside outer accordion-content as then it won't be immediate child or am I wrong?

Comment: If the markup represents a hamburger menu or other tree-like structure, I suppose the class of the divs nested in `.accordion-content` should not have `.accordion` classed wrapper, a class like  `.sub-accordion` would be more appropriate. If you'll create the structure as an unordered list (it's semantically more correct), you will see that the main list differs from the sub-lists.

Comment: You can also use the `:scope` pseudo-class with the child combinator. Something like `accordionElement.querySelectorAll(":scope > .accordion-content > a, :scope > .accordion-content > button")`